# macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 windows getting focus on mouseover

Tags: macos, mouse

As of about a week ago (no corresponding system upgrade) all windows in every app gain focus automatically on mouseover. So if I have two visible windows (in the same or different apps) and one has focus, then I mouse over the one in the background, it gets focus and is pulled to the foreground.

I can’t remember any upgrades or fresh installs of apps recently that could have caused this. Any ideas what might be going on?

[**Here is a short video illustrating the problem.**](http://cl.ly/syKx)

Comment: I would try booting/ logging in in safe mode and see if this issue continues https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht201262

Comment: Yeah, I’ve tried this and no dice.